# « dégeler » vs « décongeler »

Tags: différence

Comment utilise-t-on ces verbes correctement ?

Selon mes recherches, on utilise ***dégeler*** pour les aliments liquides et ***décongeler*** pour les aliments qui sont originellement solides, sauf que quand je regarde le nombre de résultats sur Google de certaines expressions, cela ne se vérifie pas toujours (« dégeler du pain » retourne plus de résultats que « décongeler du pain »).

Answer (score 1):

Le gel (de l’eau) se produit dès que sa température descend sous 0°C. Ainsi, le dégel se produit lorsque la température monte au dessus de 0°C.

La congélation est une opération qui consiste à baisser la température (de quelque chose) bien en dessous de la température à laquelle gèle l’eau.
Ainsi, la congélation « domestique » se fait entre -15°C et -30°C.

Encore plus froid : bien qu’on ne dise pas « Désurgeler », la surgélation s’effectue à une température encore inférieure : entre -35°C et -195°C.

Answer (score 0):

Selon le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/) :

- [Dégeler](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9D0872) signifie qu'on ramène une chose gelée à son état antérieur. *A priori* [geler](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9G0428) s'applique à un liquide qui est solidifié par l'effet du froid.
- [Décongeler](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9D0572) signifie presque la même chose excepté qu'il s'applique à une chose qui a été congelée. [Congeler](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C3574), bien qu'il puisse s'appliquer à un liquide, est plus généralement utilisé pour de la nourriture solide refroidie suffisamment pour être conservée.

Answer (score 0):

- Pour la nourriture surgelée, que l'on conserve au congélateur, le mot correct est **décongeler** mais beaucoup de gens utilisent aussi **dégeler**, d'où les résultats sur Google pour "dégeler du pain".
- Pour des phénomènes naturels comme la fonte des glaces, on utilise uniquement **dégeler**, par exemple "le lac a dégelé". Il est impossible de dire "le lac a décongelé".